# Access GLFW functions from DLL

Tags: c++, glfw, dll

My game uses DLLs as mods. Players can write DLLs which can render, play audio, print to console, etc. This works fine, however when I try to access GLFW functions, they don't seem to work properly.

`CustomMod.cpp` (compiled to DLL)

```
void runDLLCode()
{
    std::cout << glfwGetKey(Game::getWindow(), GLFW_KEY_A);
}
```

`Game.cpp` (compiled to EXE)

```
void run()
{
    //Load DLL....


    std::cout << glfwGetKey(Game::getWindow(), GLFW_KEY_A); // Prints 1
    runDLLCode();                                           // Prints 0 (should print 1 since key is still down)
    std::cout << glfwGetKey(Game::getWindow(), GLFW_KEY_A); // Prints 1
}
```

Running `std::this_thread::get_id()` provides the same thread ID across both the DLL and exe.

The address of both `Game::getWindow()` is the same as well.

Is it possible to have all print 1 when the application is run? Or is it not possible to use GLFW functions across the DLL "wall"?